# Show that every bipartite graph $G$ is a subgraph of $\Delta(G)$ regular bipartite graph.?

Tags: graph-theory

1- Show that every bipartite graph $G$ is a subgraph of $\Delta(G)$ regular bipartite graph.

2- Show that every bipartite graph $G$ is of class one that is $x_1(G)=\Delta(G)$

Comment: Questions posted here should not be phrased in language appropriate for assigning homework. It can make it look as if you're copying a question without understanding it, so that you're not really asking a question. If you don't understand what an exercise says, you can ask about that, and if you do understand what it says but don't know what to do with it, you can tell us specifically what you had difficulty with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$1)$ You can start with a bipartite graph $X,Y$ and add a bunch of isolated vertices to the side with less vertices, this gives a bipartite graph $X',Y'$. We now give an iterative process to add $1$ to the degree of one vertex in $x$ and one vertex in $y$. Applying this iteratevely to pairs of vertices with degree less than $\Delta(G)$ will terminate with a bipartite regular graph with degree $\Delta(G)$.

- Let $W$ be the graph $K_{\Delta(G),\Delta(G)}$ minus one edge (we will abuse notation and refer to this edge as $uv$). The process consists of adding a copy of $W$ to the graph and adding the edge from $x$ to $u$ and from $y$ to $v$. Thus we only added extra vertices of degree $\Delta(G)$ and increased the degree of $x$ and $y$ by $1$.

$2)$ Let $G$ be a bipartite graph, we can think of $G$ being inside a $\Delta(G)$-regular bipartite graph $S$, these graphs are of class $1$ because we can extract matchings iteratively from them. Notice that we can restict the coloring of $S$ to $G$.

Comment: thank you very much Jorge Fernández Hidalgo , i think 3 days for solve , but i can't .  your answer is very useful for me ;-)  thanks

Comment: sure no probz, glad to help.